# How to get display-name from web.xml in a Spring IoC XML Configuration

Tags: java, spring

To be exact, how can I get the value of the `<display-name>` tag under the `<web-app>` tag stored in an application's web.xml in a Spring application context configuration XML file.

Ideally I would like something like the following...

```
<bean><property value="${servletContext.servletContextName}/></bean>
```

It seem like [`ServletContext.getServletContextName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletContextName%28%29) does what I want but I can't seem to figure out how to get a handle on that in the Spring application context file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the answer is trivial in Spring 3.0.x. Per the documentation for [ServletContextFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextFactoryBean.html#ServletContextFactoryBean())

> Deprecated. as of Spring 3.0, since "servletContext" is now available as a default bean in every WebApplicationContext

So I decided to try the following and it worked!

```
<bean><property value="#{servletContext.servletContextName}/></bean>
```

Since `servletContext` object is implicitly defined we can access it via Spring EL using the `#{}` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this via the XML config.

You *can* autowire a bean to receive the `ServletContext` object (or implement `ServletContextAware`), and fetch it from that programmatically, but I don't think the XML expressions have any visibility of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the [Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)?

```
<bean>
   <property value="#{T(javax.servlet.ServletContext).getServletContextName()}"/>
</bean>
```

I suspect that would print null if it works though, since there is no context yet.

Comment: I believe what you have there is for calling a static method, is it not? In which case getServletContextName is not static.