# How to place configuration file for Tomcat with several virtual hosts?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I've got Tomcat (7 or 8) with two virtual hosts with two clones of application should work.

Each application should have it's own configuration file. And it shouldn't be placed in *.war - only somewhere in server environment.

When I have a single application in Tomcat, I can place configuration file in

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/myapp.properties"/>
```

This is how Spring will find my configuration file due to applicationContext.xml.

But when I have two hosts, I should place my configuration files in different directories.
I've added Context attribute in Host in server.xml

```
<Context docBase="" path="XXX">
    <Environment name="app.name" value="myapp1" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

Here first host gets environment variable "app.name" like "myapp1". Second host gets this variable with "myapp2" value.
I've modified

But Tomcat falls with FileNotFoundException

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...\conf\${app.name}\myapp.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The environment property that you have configured is a JNDI lookup property.
I do not think it can be read as a normal system property as in the case of 
"CATALINA_HOME".

Environment - Configure names and values for scalar environment entries that will be exposed to the web application through the JNDI InitialContext (equivalent to the inclusion of an `<env-entry>` element in the web application deployment descriptor).

Comment: Thanks. But how to store two configuration files for two applications in one Tomcat?

Comment: Correct me if I am not wrong.You shall have 2 spring configuration files for 2 applications and you can place the actual properties file in the conf folder of tomcat with 2 different names.In spring conf. file-1 : <context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/myapp1.properties"/> and In spring conf. file-2 : <context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/myapp1.properties"/>.

Comment: Actually I have two versions of the same application. So they have the same location, so I can use only property that will be configured in Tomcat container.

Comment: By 2 version means you shall have 2 war files/application specific folder in  webapps directory.Right? If that is the case you shall naturally have 2 copies of spring config files and you can do changes in those 2 spring conf file.Or you do not aim to change the spring config file and want to keep it intact ?

Comment: Yes, I have two war files that are built from same VCS repository.
I can store configuration in war, of course. But then I should overwrite this configuration file after each deploy, that's not comfortable.

Comment: Can I refer to host name (named in server.xml), for example, from applicationContext.xml?
Or can I extend classpath for each Tomcat host separately? In this case I can refer to classpath:config.properties in applicationContext.xml

Comment: Please refer to the first response here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865268/how-to-get-display-name-from-web-xml-in-a-spring-ioc-xml-configuration. This might help you.

Comment: Oh, great! Will try it and then answer.